# Error when removing a tab by ID (chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a tab manager extension. The popup generates a list of all your open tabs. I'm now attempting to add a "close" option to every single one of those tabs in the list. This is what the list looks like.

[image: Chrome Extension tab list]

It shows the tab ID, which I temporarily put there just to make sure that it's got the correct IDs. See code below:

```
let allTabs = [];

chrome.tabs.query({}, tabs => {
    allTabs = tabs;
    displayTabs();
});

function displayTabs() {
    allTabs.forEach(tab => {
        $("ul").append("<li class='tab-item'>"+ tab.id + " - " + trimTitle(tab.title) + " <a href='#' class='close-tab' id="+ tab.id +">Close tab</a></li>")
    });
}
```

So far so good. The code for closing the tab looks like this:

```
$("ul").on("click", "a", function () {
    let tabId = $(this).attr("id");

    alert(tabId);

    chrome.tabs.remove(tabId);
});
```

It takes the Tab ID from the ID attribute. I also made it alert the tab ID; so when I (for instance) close try closing the `Extensions` tab with it, I get:

[image]

Which... seems correct to me. Yet I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Error in invocation of tabs.remove([integer|array] tabIds, optional function callback): No matching signature.

Which... I do not understand. It should be the right ID, and the internet tells me that this is the way to close a tab.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Pretty sure I read that the callback is optional. Either way, I tried it but still get the same error. Thanks though.

Comment: The first parameter `tabId` is of type `integer` - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-remove. Try first converting the `tabId` to integer and then pass it to `remove`. i:e `chrome.tabs.remove(+tabId);` .

Comment: @randomSoul Ah! That did it. Thank you!

Comment: Great!. The error was `TypeError` something related to mismatch in type of parameters.

Comment: In hindsight this was a very obvious fix. Now I know where to look first next time I get a `TypeError`, haha. Thanks again! You can put this in a proper answer if you want, so I can accept & upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.attr` return value of type `string` and the `chrome.tabs.remove` function - expects first parameter of type `integer or  array of integer`. Source - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-remove.

First convert the `tabId` to integer and then pass it to the `remove` funtion.

```
$("ul").on("click", "a", function () {
    let tabId = +$(this).attr("id"); // <-- or you can use parseInt

    alert(tabId);

    chrome.tabs.remove(tabId);
});
```